# How does angular2 detect the changes in a stateful pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I created a simple stateful pipe based on the [Angular.io tutorial on pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#stateful-pipes):

```typescript
@Pipe({
    name: 'fetch',
    pure: false
})

class FetchJsonPipe  implements PipeTransform{
    private fetchedValue = 'waiting';
    private fetchedValue2 = 'waiting2';

    transform(value:string, args:string[]):any {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.fetchedValue = 'done';
            this.fetchedValue2 = 'done2';
        }, 3000);
        return this.fetchedValue2;
    }
}

@Component({ selector: 'sd-splash'
           , template: 'hello ng2 {{ "5" | fetch }}'
           , pipes: [FetchJsonPipe]
           })
```

My question is, I return `this.fetchedValue` from `#transform` immediately.
Since it's just a string, it's returned *by value*. Later, when the timeout is 
finished, I just assign the value `'done'` to a property (which is also
private).

How does Angular2 know that the intial result, `'waiting'` is not final? How
does it know that the updated value will be available through `#fetchedValue`?
The promise is not exposed at all, and Angular2 has no information on the name
of the field I store the result in.

The only clue it has is `pure == false`, which I guess instructs it to
watch the instance for changes. But I don't see how it has information on
*which field* to watch.

But it works! And I have no idea why.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular monkey patches browser events (including `setTimeout()`) using a library called Zone.js. When events happen, AngularJS triggers change detection.

With stateful pipes, AngularJS will re-evaluate the pipe on every event because the pipe result may change even with the same inputs.

With pure pipes, AngularJS will trigger change detection and re-evaluate the pipe only when one of the input changes (i.e. data coming in, or the args).

Comment: thanks! and how does it know that it should look for the `fetchedValue` property for the new value?

Comment: During change detection, angularjs checks for changes on *all* bindings.

Comment: I updated the code example to use a `#fetchedValue` and `#fetchedValue2` as well. If I return `this.fetchedValue2`, it correctly updates the value with `#fetchedValue2` when the timeout fires. My question is, how does it know that it should update the view with `#fetchedValue2` and not with `#fetchedValue`? The transform function only returns `'waiting'` initially, with no indication which property it's in. Nor the property is bound anywhere.

Comment: There is a implicit binding between the result of the pipe and view's rendering of the result. After the timeout event fires, AngularJS will re-evaluate the pipe and update all the bindings.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, I think it's probably best to look at the talk on [Zone.js](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IqtmUscE_U). 
Basically angular uses a library called zone to do a $rootScope digest after a setTimeout call completes (if it needs to)

Not only that, even after any promise resolution, a digest cycle is triggered.

This is precisely because it doesn't know which properties might have changed, so it dirty checks the entire app.